# Webscraping with Rvest losing text due to quote in content

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am attempting to use the webscraping package `rvest` to grab the species description from the website eBird. My issue is that the description text is getting cut off I believe due to quotes within the content. Examining the source for the webpage and the tag that I am looking for I see:

```
<meta name="description" content="Small flycatcher with a big, peaked head and relatively long bill. Extremely similar to several other species, especially Alder and Willow Flycatchers. Greenish-olive above and pale whitish below. Thin white eyering. Dark wings with distinct white wingbars. Very long wingtips. Best distinguished from other flycatchers by habitat and voice. Birds near the northern end of range prefer shaded ravines with mix of hemlocks and deciduous trees; farther south, found in mature deciduous forests. Tends to stay high in the canopy. Song is an explosive "pwit-SIP;" call note is a sharp "pweek." ">
```

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://ebird.org/species/acafly"

# Get list of metatag tags 
metatags <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes('meta') %>% 
  html_attr('name')

# Get which row has the description
rownum <- which(metatags == "description")

# Get content from meta tags
content <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes('meta') %>% 
  html_attr('content') 

# Get description content
description <- content[rownum]
```

The description that I have extracted from the following code gives me:

"Small flycatcher with a big, peaked head and relatively long bill. Extremely similar to several other species, especially Alder and Willow Flycatchers. Greenish-olive above and pale whitish below. Thin white eyering. Dark wings with distinct white wingbars. Very long wingtips. Best distinguished from other flycatchers by habitat and voice. Birds near the northern end of range prefer shaded ravines with mix of hemlocks and deciduous trees; farther south, found in mature deciduous forests. Tends to stay high in the canopy. Song is an explosive "

However, what I really want is:

"Small flycatcher with a big, peaked head and relatively long bill. Extremely similar to several other species, especially Alder and Willow Flycatchers. Greenish-olive above and pale whitish below. Thin white eyering. Dark wings with distinct white wingbars. Very long wingtips. Best distinguished from other flycatchers by habitat and voice. Birds near the northern end of range prefer shaded ravines with mix of hemlocks and deciduous trees; farther south, found in mature deciduous forests. Tends to stay high in the canopy. Song is an explosive **"pwit-SIP;" call note is a sharp "pweek.**"

How can I get this full description that includes the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the full description including the quotes from the first `p` tag with class `u-stack-sm`:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://ebird.org/species/acafly"

# Get description content
description <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes('p.u-stack-sm') %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  .[[1]]
description
#> [1] "Small flycatcher with a big, peaked head and relatively long bill. Extremely similar to several other species, especially Alder and Willow Flycatchers. Greenish-olive above and pale whitish below. Thin white eyering. Dark wings with distinct white wingbars. Very long wingtips. Best distinguished from other flycatchers by habitat and voice. Birds near the northern end of range prefer shaded ravines with mix of hemlocks and deciduous trees; farther south, found in mature deciduous forests. Tends to stay high in the canopy. Song is an explosive \"pwit-SIP;\" call note is a sharp \"pweek.\"\n\r\n"

url <- "https://ebird.org/species/siltea1/"

description <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes('p.u-stack-sm') %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  .[[1]]
description
#> [1] "Distinctive, but rather local and uncommon in Chile (more common in Argentina and elsewhere) in grassy wetlands, reedy marshes, and on lakes. Associates with other waterfowl, but usually is not out on open water and is easily overlooked. Readily identified by small size, dark cap, pale cheeks, and blue bill with yellow patch at base. Range does not overlap with the larger and more boldly patterned Puna Teal.\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Worked perfect thanks. Just curious do you know why the content was cut off on the meta tag?

Comment: Hi @ThomasPham. Not sure about that. Probably has to do with the double quotes around "pwit-SIP;". Looks like these have not been escaped, so that the content gets cut. The missing parts are indeed present in the meta tag. But not as part of the content attr, but as attributes themselves, i.e. the meta tag has attr "pwit-SIP", "call, "note", ...